# Getting PNTimeoutCategory error while connecting channels of PubNub Service

Tags: android, pubnub

Getting the `PNTimeoutCategory` while trying to connect to PubNub Services. Following are the `PNStatus` category we receive.

```
PNErrorData(information=null, throwable=com.pubnub.api.PubNubException),
error=true, statusCode=0, operation=PNHeartbeatOperation, tlsEnabled=false, 
uuid=null, authKey=null, origin=null, 
clientRequest=null, affectedChannels=[*************], 
affectedChannelGroups=[],
executedEndpoint=com.pubnub.api.endpoints.presence.Heartbeat@fe6406)
```

It happens sometimes, but then we have to `unsubscribe` the channels and `subscribe` again.

1. How to handle `PNTimeoutCategory` error encountered?
2. And what is the cause of this?

PNConfigs used:

```
// configuration of KEY's
    PNConfiguration pnConfiguration = new PNConfiguration();
    pnConfiguration.setPublishKey(***);
pnConfiguration.setSubscribeKey(***);
pnConfiguration.setSecretKey(***);
pnConfiguration.setAuthKey(***);

// set secure i.e. set use of SSL
pnConfiguration.setSecure(pnConfiguration.isSecure());

pnConfiguration.setNonSubscribeRequestTimeout(NON_SUSCRIBE_REQUEST_TIMEOUT);

// setting UUID as instance id
String instanceId = Utility.getInstanceId();
pnConfiguration.setUuid(instanceId);

// Set reconnect policy: LINEAR means automatic reconnects
// If a client gets disconnected from a channel, it can automatically attempt to reconnect
// to that channel and retrieve any available messages that were missed during that period.
pnConfiguration.setReconnectionPolicy(PNReconnectionPolicy.LINEAR);

pubnub = new PubNub(pnConfiguration);

// verify client connectivity to origin
pubnub.time().async(new PNCallback<PNTimeResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(PNTimeResult result, PNStatus status) {
    //logs
    }
});
```

and Pubnub lib we are using currently is
implementation 'com.pubnub:pubnub-gson:4.19.0'

Comment: It is typically poor/weak/unstable network connections that cause the heartbeat to timeout and probably means you are getting other timeouts. Another cause could be your ISP is doing some _"traffic shaping"_. If you enable TLS, then it should fix this for good. Since you are using Java/Android, make sure you are doing `pnConfiguration.setSecure(true);`. Please share your `PNConfiguration` and `new PubNub(...)` code above but redact your pub and sub keys.

Comment: @CraigConover Added the PNConfig settings and lib version currently we are using.

Comment: You asked same question again here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66616339/getting-the-pntimeoutcategory-while-trying-to-connect-to-pubnub-services so I voted to close this as duplicate.