# Getting the PNTimeoutCategory while trying to connect to PubNub Services

Tags: android, pubnub

Getting the `PNTimeoutCategory` while trying to connect to PubNub Services. Following are the `PNStatus` category we receive.

```java
    PNErrorData(information=null, throwable=com.pubnub.api.PubNubException),
    error=true, statusCode=0, operation=PNHeartbeatOperation, tlsEnabled=false, 
    uuid=null, authKey=null, origin=null, 
    clientRequest=null, affectedChannels=[*************], 
    affectedChannelGroups=[],
    executedEndpoint=com.pubnub.api.endpoints.presence.Heartbeat@fe6406)
```

It happens sometimes, but then we have to unsubscribe from channels and subscribe again.

How to handle `PNTimeoutCategory` error encountered?
And what is the cause of this?

`PNConfigs` used:

```java
    // configuration of KEY's
    PNConfiguration pnConfiguration = new PNConfiguration();
    pnConfiguration.setPublishKey(***);
    pnConfiguration.setSubscribeKey(***);
    pnConfiguration.setSecretKey(***);
    pnConfiguration.setAuthKey(***);
    
    // set secure i.e. set use of SSL
    pnConfiguration.setSecure(pnConfiguration.isSecure());
    
    pnConfiguration.setNonSubscribeRequestTimeout(NON_SUSCRIBE_REQUEST_TIMEOUT);
    
    // setting UUID as instance id
    String instanceId = Utility.getInstanceId();
    pnConfiguration.setUuid(instanceId);
    
    // Set reconnect policy: LINEAR means automatic reconnects
    // If a client gets disconnected from a channel, it can automatically attempt to reconnect
    // to that channel and retrieve any available messages that were missed during that period.
    pnConfiguration.setReconnectionPolicy(PNReconnectionPolicy.LINEAR);
    
    pubnub = new PubNub(pnConfiguration);
    
    // verify client connectivity to origin
    pubnub.time().async(new PNCallback<PNTimeResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(PNTimeResult result, PNStatus status) {
        //logs
        }
    });
```

and Pubnub lib we are using currently is implementation `com.pubnub:pubnub-gson:4.19.0`

Comment: **First**: you are on a version that is a few years old (March 29, 2018). Can you try upgrading to [latest Java SDK version - v4.35.0](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/sdks/java/)? **Second**: what is the actual value you have for `NON_SUSCRIBE_REQUEST_TIMEOUT`? It is not recommended that you change this value, but there are some edge cases where it is warranted. Let me know that value and the requirement driving that value.

Comment: Thanks for reply. 1. NON_SUSCRIBE_REQUEST_TIMEOUT = 15 sec(default is 10sec), Actually previously few months back also we receive this error, and in documentation it was mentioned that this could be due to the Timeout in Non-Subscriber request. That's why we have added this incremented timeout value. 2. We will increase the Build version. 3. In setSecure(pnConfiguration.isSecure()) do you suggest it to make harcoded true ?

Comment: 10s should be plenty and the *Heartbeat* is not a critical operation and in fact, you can disable them unless you are setting the `presenceTimeout` lower than the default of 300. But that typically isn't necessary either except for some requirements. Are you getting timeout errors for any other operations like Publish, Fetching Messages, etc.? For `setSecure` (TLS, aka HTTPS), it should default to *true*, but go ahead and set it. There should be no reason to see to *false*.

Comment: No as of now not encountered Timeout error for the Publish and Fetching of messages. Btw we have adopted changes for the Lib upgrade and SetSecure configuration changes. We hope it will resolved the issue.

Comment: Cool, like I said, you can probably disable those Heartbeats. Report back with your results. I would like to write a formal answer for this post. Cheers!

Comment: An update, users are still facing the issue, where sometime they are not able to get data when pushed from back end. The internet connection is OK.

Comment: Please submit all the details to the PN Support team - support@pubnub.com - your sub-key, the code, errors you are seeing, reproduce with [SDK logging enabled](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/sdks/java/troubleshooting) and attach log file. Also include link to the post so we can answer back when we resolve the ticket.